# Viewing all my posts to all Stack Exchange sites in reverse chronological order?

Tags: support, network-profile

I am able to visit any Stack Exchange site and view all my posts to such site.
However, I would like to be able to view all of my posts to all Stack Exchange
sites in reverse chronological order, all on one page, and not just per-site
posts. Is there a way to achieve this via the user interface?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3083067/john-sonderson) already lists this.

Go to your network profile (there is a link on each of your regular profiles):

[image: network profile link]

Then click *Activity*, then filter to *posts*.

See https://stackexchange.com/users/3083067/john-sonderson?tab=activity:

[image: Activity tab, with the posts filter enabled]

Comment: But not in *reverse* chronological order....

Comment: @Shokhet: This *is* in reverse chronological order. From start to finish (oldest first) is chronological order. Newest first, going *backwards in time from there* is the reverse order.

Comment: I believe he wants to see them oldest first, not newest first....but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Shokhet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_chronology

Comment: @Shokhet: They are asking for reverse chronological order. They could've misunderstood what that means, but the posts are listed in that order.

Comment: Like I always say; I've been wrong before, and I'll do it again. Thanks for explaining! :) [ *my misunderstanding was because I didn't understand "reverse chronology"* ]

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters and @nicael for your answers. The trick I was missing out on is I was not realizing that to do this I had to first go to the `stackexchange.com` site which acts as a parent site for all of the other Stack Exchange sites and then click on my user name and activity tab and posts subtab. Instead, if you do the same thing from a specific Stack Exchange site results only show up for that site. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSonderson: your profile on any site contains a link; look for *network profile* on the top right.

Answer (score 2):

You can see all of your posts in reverse chronological order by going to https://stackexchange.com/users/3083067/john-sonderson?tab=activity, and choosing "posts".

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I don't see a button to force forward (oldest first) chronological order on the interface. This is not what I was looking for, but given that the question came up, it would be nice to have an option to view the posts in (forward) chronological order as well. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSonderson: you cannot change the sort order.

Comment: OK. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

In your network profile, you can find only your latest 100 posts.

If you want to see all your posts, network-wide, you can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/724214/my-cross-network-posts-in-reverse-chronological-order). It shows all your posts, even the tag wikis you've created.

To run the query, you have to give it your network-wide account id. It is the number in your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3083067/john-sonderson): 3043067.

On the same way, you can list also the posts posted by others.

You can see the posts created until last monday dawn.

[image]