# Why does this SEDE query think that the MathOverflow Meta is mathoverflow.meta.stackexchange.com?

Tags: bug, data-explorer, per-site-meta

I ran a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/724214/my-cross-network-posts-in-reverse-chronological-order) created by [@peterh](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300953) to find all my network posts.  It works perfectly for the task, but it believes that all my posts made to [MathOverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net) were actually made to https://mathoverflow.meta.stackexchange.com, which does not exist.  My subject question is "why does it think this?", but I guess my real question is "shouldn't it stop thinking this?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a fault of the query, not of Stack Exchange. MathOverflow should be special-cased, right now it triggers this part of `SiteToDb`:

```sql
      WHEN
        name LIKE 'StackExchange.%'
      THEN
        RIGHT(name, LEN(name) - 14) + '.stackexchange.com'
```

That's an old query, but there are better ways to generate links in cross-site queries. I regularly run those, so I designed a solution based on a community-maintained list of sites and database names: [How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359794/295232)